# 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

When I run this code then following error is encountered, I am new to programming and I know I have bunch of useless arrays. I don't know where my error is as I have declared `j` as an array. I am completely out of ideas.

```
import pyodbc,nltk,array,re,itertools
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=information_schema;User=root; Password=1234;Option=3;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("use collegedatabase ;")
cursor.execute("select *  from sampledata ; ")
cnxn.commit()
s=[]
j=[]
x=[]
words = []
w = []
sfq = []
POS=[]
wnl = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
p = []
clean= []
l =[]
tupletolist= []
results = []
aux = []
regex = re.compile("\w+\.")
pp = []
array1=[]

f = open("C:\\Users\\vchauhan\\Desktop\\tupletolist.txt","w")
for entry in cursor:
    s.append(entry.injury_type),j.append(entry.injury_desc) 

def isAcceptableChar(character):
    return character not in "~!@#$%^&*()_+`1234567890-={}|:<>?[]\;',/."


from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
english_stops = set(stopwords.words('english'))
for i in range(0,200):
    j.append(filter(isAcceptableChar, j[i]))
    w.append([word for word in word_tokenize(j[i].lower()) if word not in english_stops])
    for j in range (0,len(w[i])):
        results = regex.search(w[i][j])
            if results:
                str.rstrip(w[i][j],'.')
for a in range(0 , 200):
    sfq.append(" ".join(w[a]))

from nltk.stem import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

for i in range (0,200):
    pp.append(len(w[i]))

for a in range (0,200):
    p.append(word_tokenize(sfq[a]))
    POS.append([wnl.lemmatize(t) for t in p[a]])
    x.append(nltk.pos_tag(POS[a]))
    clean.append((re.sub('()[\]{}'':/\-[(",)]','',str(x[a]))))
    cursor.execute("update sampledata SET POS = ? where SRNO = ?", (re.sub('()[\]{}'':/\-[(",)]','',str(x[a]))), a)

for i in range (0,len(array1)):
    results.append(regex.search(array1[i][0]))
    if results[i] is not None:
        aux.append(i)

f.write(str(w))
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vchauhan\Desktop\regexsolution_try.py", line 37, in <module>
  j.append(filter(isAcceptableChar, j[i]))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Looks like you got a practical lesson in why to not use 1-letter variable names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`j` has been used a a list as well as an integer.
Use `j` only for integer name, name the list to something else.

```
j.append(filter(isAcceptableChar, j[i]))    # j is not a list here,it is an int.
w.append([word for word in word_tokenize(j[i].lower()) if word not in english_stops])
for j in range (0,len(w[i])):               # here j is an int
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a close look at the following piece of your code:

```
for i in range(0,200):
    j.append(filter(isAcceptableChar, j[i]))
    w.append([word for word in word_tokenize(j[i].lower()) if word not in english_stops])
    for j in range (0,len(w[i])):
```

Notice how you first call `.append` on `j` (which you had initialized with a list earlier), then use it as a loop variable nested in the same loop.

Use better, meaningful variable names in your code to avoid this class of errors. Rename either the loop variable or the module-level list variable.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to use the variable 'j' as a int-counter in the loop, i.e. the list 'j' is replaced by an int 'j' where you cannot append something. Solution: Rename the variables with more sophisticated names...

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is broken, but it seems like it's this line that is the culprit:

```
for j in range (0,len(w[i])):
```

The first time, `j` is an array, but then you hide it with the int `j`. It's hard to discover since what causes the error seems to happen *after* it, but since it's in a loop, that's not really true. Try renaming this integer.